# How to write a natural join on eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to write a natural joint on eloquent but without success, please could you help me? 
So my sql request is:

```
SELECT * FROM `case_managers` NATURAL JOIN risks
```

I have did

```
Case_managers::join('risks')->get()
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'with' instead of join like

```
Case_managers::with('risk')->get();
```

where risk is your model name related to risks table.

Answer (score -1):

Create  a relationship in `Case_managers` model.

```
  public function risks()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Risk','foreign_key','local_key');
   //if there is going to be multiple entries,change `hasOne` as `hasMany`
  }
```

You can access risks as

```
  $res = Case_managers::find($id);
  echo $res->risks->risk_field; //risk_field is the column name you want from risks table
 //if `hasMany` is the relationship,use `foreach`
 foreach($res->risks as $risk)
 {
   echo $risk->risk_field;
 }
```